# Performance difference between view and stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, view

I want to know which gives better performance : View or a stored procedure.

If same select query (say with some joins ) is written in both i.e. View and a stored procedure then which one would give better performance . or what should one option for in such a case.

Comment: What happened when you ran tests on both?

Comment: Why don't you run both and measure time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are very different concepts, to be honest. A view is a single result set that presents information from one or more sources in a single query statement. It has a fixed schema (i.e. the result set it returns will always have the same columns) and it has no parameters.

Stored procedures are simply stored queries. They can have parameters, you can choose which parts execute or not with control logic, they can create and destroy objects in the database, they can return any number of result sets.

Answer (score 2):

View---

Does not accepts parameters.
Can be used as a building block in large query.
Can contain only one single Select query.
Cannot perform modification to any table.
Can be used (sometimes) as the target for Insert, update, delete queries.

Stored Procedure---

Accept parameters.
Cannot be used as a building block in large query.
Can contain several statement like if, else, loop etc.
Can perform modification to one or several tables.
Cannot be used as the target for Insert, update, delete queries.